# Disjoint alignments inside multiline equations

Tags: alignment

I am trying to use align and friends to typeset something -- it's between source and math.

The alignment requirement is to line up '='s and patterns on the left of Haskell-like equations.

The disjointness requirement is that the first line — a type — should not affect the remaining lines.

[image: Screenshot]

The code I've come up with (tolerable look) is terrible LaTeX!

Can someone help improve it?

[Those `\qquads` are to push it to the left, I could not get fleqn to work. The lipsum is for verifying column fitting]

```
% Intended LaTeX compiler: pdflatex
\documentclass[conference,a4paper]{IEEEtran}

\usepackage{egreg}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{lipsum}



\newcommand\scalemath[2]{\scalebox{#1}{\mbox{\ensuremath{\displaystyle #2}}}}
\newcommand{\gufx}[1] {\scalemath{1.1}{\text{\,\guilsinglleft{#1}\guilsinglright}}\,\,}
\newcommand*{\Scale}[2][4]{\scalebox{#1}{$#2$}}%
\newcommand{\cc}{\mathbin{\!::\!}}
\newcommand{\pp}{\mathrel{\,+\!\!\!+\,}}
%% \newcommand{\sub}{\scalebox{0.6}[1.0]{\( - \)}}
%% \newcommand{\plus}{\scalebox{0.8}{\( + \)}}
\date{}
\title{Some Title}
\begin{document}


\author{\IEEEauthorblockN{John Doe}
}
\maketitle
\thispagestyle{plain}
\pagestyle{plain}
\begin{abstract}
Bla Bla
\end{abstract}
\begin{IEEEkeywords}
Key Key
\end{IEEEkeywords}
\section{Top level head}
\label{sec:org7975432}
\lipsum[1]
\begingroup
\addtolength{\jot}{-.25em}
\small
\begin{alignat*}{6}
\begin{alignedat}{6}
&c&&:\,\,&& \mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{N}&&\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\quad\;\\
\end{alignedat}\\[1em]
\begin{alignedat}{40}
&0     &&\gufx{c} &&(r{+}1) &&= &&\,0\\
&n     &&\gufx{c} &&0     &&= &&\,1\\
&(n{+}1) &&\gufx{c} &&r     &&= &&\,n \gufx{c} \! r  + n \gufx{c} \!(r{-}1)&&\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\quad
\end{alignedat}
\end{alignat*}

\lipsum[2]

\begin{alignat*}{6}
\begin{alignedat}{6}
&ce&&:[t] \rightarrow \mathbb{N} \rightarrow [[t]]\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\quad\\
\end{alignedat}\\[1.3em]
 \begin{alignedat}{40}
 &\,[\,\,] &&\gufx{ce}&&(r{+}1)&&= [\,\,]\\
 &\,xs &&\gufx{ce} &&0 &&= [[\,\,]]\\
 &\,(x\cc xs) &&\gufx{ce} &&r &&= xs \gufx{ce}\! r {\mathrel{\pp}} [x\cc y \mid y \in (xs \gufx{ce} (r{-}1))] \qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\quad
\end{alignedat}
\end{alignat*}
\endgroup
\lipsum[1-4]
\end{document}
```

---

### Added after Zarko's answer.

I tried `fleqn*` and `flalign*`.  Neither work

Answer (score 3):

Less horrible input using `IEEEeqnarraybox` (see [the manual](https://moser-isi.ethz.ch/docs/typeset_equations.pdf)) and a “dirty trick”

```
\documentclass[conference,a4paper]{IEEEtran}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{newtx}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newcommand\scalemath[2]{\scalebox{#1}{\mbox{\ensuremath{\displaystyle #2}}}}
\newcommand{\gufx}[1] {\mathrel{\scalemath{1.1}{\text{\guilsinglleft{#1}\guilsinglright}}}}
\newcommand*{\Scale}[2][4]{\scalebox{#1}{$#2$}}%
\newcommand{\cc}{\mathbin{\!::\!}}
\newcommand{\pp}{\mathrel{\,+\!\!\!+\,}}
%% \newcommand{\sub}{\scalebox{0.6}[1.0]{\( - \)}}
%% \newcommand{\plus}{\scalebox{0.8}{\( + \)}}

\newenvironment{leftdisplay}[1][\normalsize]
 {$$\hspace{0pt}\begin{minipage}{\displaywidth}#1}
 {\end{minipage}\hspace{1000pt minus 1fil}$$}

\begin{document}

\author{\IEEEauthorblockN{John Doe}}
\title{Some Title}
\date{}

\maketitle

\begin{abstract}
Bla Bla
\end{abstract}

\begin{IEEEkeywords}
Key Key
\end{IEEEkeywords}

\section{Top level head}
\label{sec:org7975432}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{leftdisplay}
\begin{IEEEeqnarraybox}{lClCl}
\IEEEeqnarraymulticol{5}{l}{%
  c\colon\mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{N}%
} \\[1ex]
0       & \gufx{c} & (r{+}1) & = & 0 \\
n       & \gufx{c} & 0       & = & 1 \\
(n{+}1) & \gufx{c} & r       & = & n \gufx{c} \! r  + n \gufx{c} \!(r{-}1)
\end{IEEEeqnarraybox}
\end{leftdisplay}
\lipsum[2][1-5]
\begin{leftdisplay}[\small]
\begin{IEEEeqnarraybox}{lClCl}
\IEEEeqnarraymulticol{5}{l}{ce\colon [t] \rightarrow \mathbb{N} \rightarrow [[t]]} \\[1.5ex]
[\,\,]    & \gufx{ce} & (r{+}1) & = & [\,\,]\\
xs        & \gufx{ce} & 0       & = & [[\,\,]]\\
(x\cc xs) & \gufx{ce} & r       & = & xs \gufx{ce} r {\mathrel{\pp}} 
                                      [x\cc y \mid y \in (xs \gufx{ce} (r{-}1))]
\end{IEEEeqnarraybox}
\end{leftdisplay}
\lipsum[1-5]

\end{document}
```

[image]

The `leftdisplay` environment has an optional argument to set a smaller font. On the other hand, with `newtx` the second display actually needn't be `\small`:

[image]

The `IEEEeqnarray` and `IEEEeqnarraybox` use `\IEEEeqnarrayjot`, not `\jot`. You can add the setting in the optional argument to `leftdisplay`. Here I commented out `newtx` (but the result is definitely lower quality). Probably the amount should be different in the `\small` part.

```
\documentclass[conference,a4paper]{IEEEtran}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{graphicx}
%\usepackage{newtx}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newcommand\scalemath[2]{\scalebox{#1}{\mbox{\ensuremath{\displaystyle #2}}}}
\newcommand{\gufx}[1] {\mathrel{\scalemath{1.1}{\text{\guilsinglleft{#1}\guilsinglright}}}}
\newcommand*{\Scale}[2][4]{\scalebox{#1}{$#2$}}%
\newcommand{\cc}{\mathbin{\!::\!}}
\newcommand{\pp}{\mathrel{\,+\!\!\!+\,}}
%% \newcommand{\sub}{\scalebox{0.6}[1.0]{\( - \)}}
%% \newcommand{\plus}{\scalebox{0.8}{\( + \)}}

\newenvironment{leftdisplay}[1][\normalsize]
 {$$\hspace{0pt}\begin{minipage}{\displaywidth}#1}
 {\end{minipage}\hspace{1000pt minus 1fil}$$}

\begin{document}

\author{\IEEEauthorblockN{John Doe}}
\title{Some Title}
\date{}

\maketitle

\begin{abstract}
Bla Bla
\end{abstract}

\begin{IEEEkeywords}
Key Key
\end{IEEEkeywords}

\section{Top level head}
\label{sec:org7975432}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{leftdisplay}[\addtolength\IEEEnormaljot{-0.25em}]
\begin{IEEEeqnarraybox}{lClCl}
\IEEEeqnarraymulticol{5}{l}{%
  c\colon\mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{N}%
} \\[1ex]
0       & \gufx{c} & (r{+}1) & = & 0 \\
n       & \gufx{c} & 0       & = & 1 \\
(n{+}1) & \gufx{c} & r       & = & n \gufx{c} \! r  + n \gufx{c} \!(r{-}1)
\end{IEEEeqnarraybox}
\end{leftdisplay}
\lipsum[2][1-5]
\begin{leftdisplay}[\small\addtolength\IEEEnormaljot{-0.25em}]
\begin{IEEEeqnarraybox}{lClCl}
\IEEEeqnarraymulticol{5}{l}{ce\colon [t] \rightarrow \mathbb{N} \rightarrow [[t]]} \\[1.5ex]
[\,\,]    & \gufx{ce} & (r{+}1) & = & [\,\,]\\
xs        & \gufx{ce} & 0       & = & [[\,\,]]\\
(x\cc xs) & \gufx{ce} & r       & = & xs \gufx{ce} r {\mathrel{\pp}} 
                                      [x\cc y \mid y \in (xs \gufx{ce} (r{-}1))]
\end{IEEEeqnarraybox}
\end{leftdisplay}
\lipsum[1-5]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Can't find newtx. When I replace by newtxtext I get can't open type 1 font. No PDF produced

Comment: @Rusi Faulty or not up-to-date installation. Remove `\usepackage{newtx}`.

Comment: Tnx egreg. But I want to do (something like) `\addtolength{\jot}{-.25em}`. I tried putting it in a number of places (in your new env and outside) but either no effect. Or it squeezes the wrong thing!

Comment: @Rusi See edit.

Comment: Is there something like IEEEeqnarrayjot? The IEEEtran.cls which kpsewhich finds doesn't seem to have it. Nor does google. Changing it seems to produce no effect. Otoh removing newtx didn't cause a problem (your 1st edition!)

Answer (score 2):

See,  if this is close to desired code:

```
\documentclass[conference,a4paper]{IEEEtran}

%\usepackage{egreg}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{amssymb, amsthm}
\usepackage{nccmath, mathtools}
\usepackage{lipsum}


\newcommand\scalemath[2]{\scalebox{#1}{\mbox{\ensuremath{\displaystyle #2}}}}
\newcommand{\gufx}[1] {\scalemath{1.1}{\text{\,\guilsinglleft{#1}\guilsinglright}}\,\,}
\newcommand*{\Scale}[2][4]{\scalebox{#1}{$#2$}}%
\newcommand{\cc}{\mathbin{\!::\!}}
\newcommand{\pp}{\mathrel{\,+\!\!\!+\,}}


\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{fleqn}
\begin{alignat*}{3}
&\mathrlap{c:\;\mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}}\\
&0       & \gufx{c}  & (r{+}1) &&= 0    \\
&n       & \gufx{c}  & 0       &&= 1    \\
&(n{+}1) & \gufx{c}  &         &&= n \gufx{c} \! r  + n\gufx{c} \!(r{-}1)
\end{alignat*}
\end{fleqn}

\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Edit: removed equation numbers.

Comment: No eqn numbers pls. Otherwise seems fine!

Comment: @Rusi, of you need only add asterisk to environment name. Corrected in edited answer.

Comment: Yeah Tnx zarko. I figured...